# Fastest Conversion of Array of Guid to String and Back?

Tags: arrays, linq, guid

With .NET 4.0, I sometimes have a Guid[] or 200 items that all need conversion to string[], and sometimes I have to do the reverse.

What is the fastest/smartest way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: This is something you can and should test for yourself. Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: myguids.Select(Guid.Parse).ToArray()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An alternative to LINQ is [**`Array.ConvertAll()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) in this case:

```
Guid[] guidArray = new Guid[100];
...
string[] stringArray = Array.ConvertAll(guidArray, x => x.ToString());
guidArray = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, x => Guid.Parse(x));
```

Runtime performance is probably the same as LINQ, although it is probably a tiny bit faster since it's going from and to array directly instead of an enumeration first.

Comment: +1 for performance, because it can preallocate an array of the correct size.

Comment: That is awesome. I forgot about ConvertAll() completely. Thanks!

Comment: @dagkbyk @Snowy:  If performance is a consideration, I would say you should profile them - I would guess the LINQ version is actually going to be faster, because it does not need to allocate an array *(it just returns the strings as you request them)*.  Also, it does not require using arrays, which is always a good thing.

Comment: @BlueRaja: the question was specifically about **array** conversion, if arrays are not needed it's a different story

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you wanted to use LINQ, `myList.Select(o => o.ToString())` will do it.

Otherwise, filling a `List` with a `foreach` loop is almost as succinct, and will work with older versions of .Net.

Answer (score 2):

See if it helps:

```
Guid[] guids = new Guid[200];
var guidStrings = guids.Select(g => g.ToString());
var revertedGuids = guidStrings.Select(g => Guid.Parse(g));
```

Comment: I just think you are looking for a most efficient way for the conversion; I am not sure, but it's the easiest way.